# What's wrong in my amplifier circuit?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, amplifier, circuit-design

[image: Amplifier Circuit]

I am desinging a amplifier circuit. But the output is showing linear. please help.

Comment: what is the problem? ... what were you expecting?

Comment: C1 and C2 prevent any DC current from flowing through the transistor. Also, you are holding the transistor base at a fixed voltage - there won;'t be any signal there. The circuit cannot work as drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit design had many errors.
Here is a simulation using your parts without R1, with the input level reduced and with a much higher resistance for the load R1.:
[image: transistor]

Answer (score 1):

V1 has the base of Q1 clamped at 1.5 V.  If the intent is to bias the base-emitter junction at 1.5 V to set the output DC operating point, better to use a 2-resistor voltage divider between V2 and GND.

Also, there is no DC path to GND from the emitter, so the transistor cannot function.  C1 will charge up to (V1 - 0.6) V, and then the transistor will just sit there with zero collector current.

Ask yourself:

What is the purpose of RC?

What is the purpose of R1?

Are these parts positioned correctly in the circuit to do their functions?